# Running script twice at time

Tags: linux, bash

I'm making a little simple script to improve the efficienty of my work team.
The script simply searches a file that the user gives as param.

./check_file test_file.xml

I used only `ls` and `cp` commands and there's no log or temporary files.

My question is: should I put a .lock file to be sure that the script runs only once at time or can I avoid this control?

Usually I create a lock file, because my scripts write temporary files and if two users run at the same moment the script, it explodes.

Thanks!

Comment: If your script has no side effects, don't bother with this kind of check.

Comment: Even if your script does generate temporary files, you can always generate unique filenames so, even then, the lock would just be a matter of not using to much ressources (CPU, or IO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, no.  I would recommend avoiding temporary files as much as possible, preferring pipes instead. However, I doubt it's always possible to avoid temporary files, so when I have to, I use `$$` in the filename (current process ID or PID).  So if you're using `/tmp/check_file.tmp` as your temporary filename, instead use `/tmp/check_file.$$.tmp` - then two processes can run at a time, each with their own PID, and not overlap.

Slightly more advanced is to also use `${TMP:-/tmp}` as the temporary directory instead of just `/tmp` - that way users can specify a different directory for each run, and thereby also avoid any overlaps.